# How to add Brackets around a word which is between certain characters using Regex?

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to add brackets around a string which is segeraged by some characters;

For example, I have a string like: "Red => Orange => Yellow blue => Grey,black"

I would like to get something like "[ Red ] => [ Orange ] => [ Yellow blue ] => [ Grey,black ]"
(space before and brackets also present)

I have tried several approaches in R using stingr package but I am unable to get this above pattern.

Thanks in advance for your help

I have tried to use stringr function in R str_replace_all(str,"\b\w+","[\1]") and str_replace_all(str,"\b\w+","[") but the function replaces the character specified, I am unable to find a method to replace before a character

Comment: Maybe `paste0("[ ", paste(strsplit(x, " => ", fixed=TRUE)[[1]], collapse=" ] => [ "), " ]")
`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew post as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```r
x <- "Red => Orange => Yellow blue => Grey,black"
paste0("[ ", paste(strsplit(x, " => ", fixed=TRUE)[[1]], collapse=" ] => [ "), " ]")
paste0("[ ", gsub("\\s*=>\\s*", " ] => [ ", x), " ]")
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/Z66MZg). Both solutions yield `[1] "[ Red ] => [ Orange ] => [ Yellow blue ] => [ Grey,black ]"`.

The `gsub("\\s*=>\\s*", " ] => [ ", x)` part replaces all occurrences of zero or more whitespaces, `=>`, zero or more whitespaces with space + `] => [` + space.

`paste0("[ ", gsub(...), " ]")` is used to enclose the whole string with `[`  and  `]`.